# Can you create views in Amazon Athena?

Tags: amazon-athena

Is it possible to create views in Amazon Athena?

Since an External table is essentially metadata for data stored in files on S3, there's no transformation involved.  Therefore, you can't handle data inconsistencies.  Quite often, this can result in tables being defined with lots of string fields.

Can you create a view over the top of the External table that can contain the transformation logic, allowing users to query a "cleansed" view of the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While that is a nice feature that you are looking for,

AWS Athena does not support creating any view.

Reference Documentation of supported DDL's:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/language-reference.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking through those docs but must have missed it!

Answer (score 11):

Looks like they have added this support now [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/views.html)