# Create AWS Athena View Programmatically via Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-athena

I am trying to create Athena Views using SQL.
And to be fair, I have achieve this - almost.

```
resource "null_resource" "views" {
    provisioner     "local-exec" {

        ## success using file://
        #command = "aws athena start-query-execution --query-string file://query11.sql  --output json --query-execution-context Database=${aws_athena_database.metadb.id} --result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://xxxxxxx2"

        ## fails when using string
        command = "aws athena start-query-execution --query-string \"CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW query11 AS SELECT * FROM  meta.getresources_vw\" --output json --query-execution-context Database=${aws_athena_database.metadb.id} --result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://xxxxxxx2"
        }
}
```

In the code, the `command` line that uses `file` to pass in the sql code, works perfectly.

However, the `command` line that tries to pass the sql in as a string - fails.

I have tried wrapping the string in single quotes, double quotes; escaped with a backslash and not .... all to no improvement.

The error when using a string is thus :

> null_resource.views: Provisioning with 'local-exec'...
>   null_resource.views (local-exec): Executing: ["cmd" "/C" "aws athena
>   start-query-execution --query-string \"CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW query11
>   AS SELECT * FROM  meta.getresources_vw\" --output json
>   --query-execution-context Database=testbug --result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://xxxxxxx2"] null_resource.views (local-exec):
>   usage: aws [options]   [ ...]
>   [parameters] null_resource.views (local-exec): To see help text, you
>   can run:
>
> null_resource.views (local-exec):   aws help null_resource.views
>   (local-exec):   aws  help null_resource.views (local-exec):
>   aws   help
>
> null_resource.views (local-exec): Unknown options: REPLACE, VIEW,
>   query11, AS, SELECT, *, FROM, meta.getresources_vw", OR
>
> Error: Error running command 'aws athena start-query-execution
>   --query-string "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW query11 AS SELECT * FROM  meta.getresources_vw" --output json --query-execution-context
>   Database=testbug --result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://xxxxxxx2':
>   exit status 255. Output: usage: aws [options]  
>   [ ...] [parameters] To see help text, you can run:
>
> aws help   aws  help   aws   help
>
> Unknown options: REPLACE, VIEW, query11, AS, SELECT, *, FROM,
>   meta.getresources_vw", OR

Interestingly enough, if I copy the command shown in the last part of the error message, and paste in directly into the CLI; it executes with success.

```
aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW query11 AS SELECT * FROM meta.getresources_vw" --output json --query-execution-context Database=testbug --result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://xxxxxxx2
```

Comment: You can find an example of how to do it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370023/1109

Comment: Thanks Theo. In the end, I decided that using local_exec was not going to be robust enough for my use case. I now upload the ddl to s3 and use a lambda to synchronise and execute against the database.